# Find 2d points in a box

Tags: java, algorithm, 2d, point

I am lookin for an algorithmn to get the fastest way to find all points 2D (x,y) that are in a box (a box is defined by 2 points: lowerLeft and upperRight).

Imagine we have 2 million points in a 2D space.

In that 2D space I create a box somewhere from 2 points, one is lower left and the other is upper right. 
What is the fastest way to get all the points that are in the box?
Here is the java test with the worst scenario: loop each point (2 millions!) and determine if it's inside the box. 
I am sure we can get really faster if the list of points is ordered first...

Do you have ideas?

```
public class FindPointsInBox {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // List of 2,000,000 points (x,y)
    List<Point> allPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for(int i=0; i<2000000; i++) {
        allPoints.add(new Point(46 - (Math.random()), -74 - (Math.random())));
    }

    // Box defined by 2 points: lowerLeft and upperRight
    List<Point> pointsInBox = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Point lowerLeft = new Point(44.91293325430085, -74.25107363281245);
    Point upperRight = new Point(45.3289676752705, -72.93820742187495);

    Date t1 = new Date();

    // TODO: What is the fastest way to find all points contained in box
    for(int i=0; i<allPoints.size(); i++) {
        if(isPointInBox(allPoints.get(i), lowerLeft, upperRight))
            pointsInBox.add(allPoints.get(i));
    }
    Date t2 = new Date();
    System.out.println(pointsInBox.size() + " points in box");
    System.out.println(t2.getTime()-t1.getTime() + "ms");
}

private static boolean isPointInBox(Point p, Point lowerLeft, Point upperRight) {
    return (
        p.getX() >= lowerLeft.getX() &&
        p.getX() <= upperRight.getX()   &&
        p.getY() >= lowerLeft.getY() &&
        p.getY() <= upperRight.getY());
}
}
```

Comment: The answers below show that you need to be a bit clearer about your problem: specifically, *when* are you constrained by time?  If you are allowed to spend processing time as points are added, but require a inside-the-box query to be fast, then Mikhail Vladimirov's idea of pre-computation will help.  However, if you are literally just given 2 million points and have to find a solution as fast as possible, then Grigor Gevorgyan is correct: there is no faster solution.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to specify that this is the time between t1 and t2 that is important for me. I can spend processing time when points are added. So Quadtree as Mikhail Vladimirov suggested is the perfect solution for me. Thansk guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your space into square cells.  For each cell store list of points that sit in the cell.  For given rectangle first find all cells that intersect with it, then iterate through points in these cells and test which of them are in the rectangle.  Here is code demonstrating this approach:

```
public class PointsIndex {
    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    private final int rows;
    private final int cols;
    private final List<Point> [][] cells;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public PointsIndex (
        int width, int height, int rows, int cols)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;

        cells = (List<Point> [][])new List<?> [rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            cells [i] = (List<Point> [])new List<?> [cols];
    }

    public void addPoint (int x, int y)
    {
        int r = x * rows / width;
        int c = y * cols / height;

        List <Point> cell = cells [r][c];
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new ArrayList<Point>();
            cells [r][c] = cell;
        }

        cell.add (new Point (x, y));
    }

    public Point [] getPoints (int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        int r1 = x * rows / width;
        int r2 = (x + w - 1) * rows / width;
        int c1 = y * cols / height;
        int c2 = (y + h - 1) * cols / height;

        ArrayList<Point> result = new ArrayList<Point>();

        for (int r = r1; r <= r2; r++)
            for (int c = c1; c <= c2; c++)
            {
                List <Point> cell = cells [r][c];
                if (cell != null)
                {
                    if (r == r1 || r == r2 || c == c1 || c == c2)
                    {
                        for (Point p: cell)
                            if (p.x > x && p.x < x + w && p.y > y && p.y < y + h)
                                result.add (p);
                    }
                    else result.addAll (cell);
                }
            }

        return result.toArray(new Point [result.size()]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random ();

        PointsIndex index = new PointsIndex(1000000, 1000000, 100, 100);
        List <Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>(1000000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            int x = r.nextInt(1000000);
            int y = r.nextInt(1000000);

            index.addPoint(x, y);
            points.add (new Point (x, y));
        }

        long t;

        t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Point [] choosen1 = index.getPoints(456789, 345678, 12345, 23456);
        System.out.println (
            "Fast method found " + choosen1.length + " points in " + 
            (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) + " ms");

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (456789, 345678, 12345, 23456);

        List <Point> choosen2 = new ArrayList<Point>();

        t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (Point p: points)
        {
            if (rect.contains(p))
                choosen2.add (p);
        }
        System.out.println(
            "Slow method found " + choosen2.size () + " points in " + 
            (System.currentTimeMillis() - t) + " ms");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Improving on Mikhails answer (I can't comment yet) you could utilise quadtrees http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree. This is what Mikhail is talking about, I think, and works by partitioning space into a grid. If there are many points in a partition it is itself partitioned into a small grid.

When selecting points one can then compare the extents of the partitions to quickly exclude several points if their containing rectangle does not intersect with your selection rectangle.

The quadtree requires O(n log n) operations for creation on average while a selecting a bunch of points requires O(log n).

Comment: To be extremely pedantic, selecting a bunch of points requires O(p * log n) where n is the total number of points and p is the number of points in the box.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is linear, and you have no way to do better, because you have at least to read the input data.